# Unable to understand the concept of server for chat in android

Tags: android, server

Since I am new to android I am confused with the concept of server for android app. After going through different tutorials I landed up at openfire server. I have done with setting up the server on my computer. If I turn off my computer the server will be closed and app will stop working I guess. How the real time chatting app work. How to get a real time server which will be available to the user 24/7. Please help me get rid off it.

Comment: If you are using your own local machine as the server, yes you need to keep it up 24/7 running. Else you can use the server's available online for a monthly or yearly fee, kind of having your own website.

Comment: Can I use my website server for the app as well?

Comment: Yes. You can. Browser or app, all make the same server requests.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have setup server on your local machine. This requires your system to be turned on always. Try hosting it in a third party environment. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you suggest some third party enironment?